# Use of findall and parenthesis in Python

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract all letters *after* the `+` sign or at the beginning of a string like this:

```
formula = "X+BC+DAF"
```

I tried so, and I do not want to see the `+` sign in the result. I wish see only `['X', 'B', 'D']`.

```
>>> re.findall("^[A-Z]|[+][A-Z]", formula)
['X', '+B', '+D']
```

When I grouped with parenthesis, I got this strange result:

```
re.findall("^([A-Z])|[+]([A-Z])", formula)
[('X', ''), ('', 'B'), ('', 'D')]
```

Why it created tuples when I try to group ? How to write the regexp directly such that it returns `['X', 'B', 'D']` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there are any capturing groups in the regular expression then [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) returns only the values captured by the groups. If there are no groups the entire matched string is returned.

> `re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)`
>
> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. **If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group.** Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the beginning of another match.

---

> How to write the regexp directly such that it returns ['X', 'B', 'D'] ?

Instead of using a capturing group you can use a non-capturing group:

```
>>> re.findall(r"(?:^|\+)([A-Z])", formula)
['X', 'B', 'D']
```

Or for this specific case you could try a simpler solution using a word boundary:

```
>>> re.findall(r"\b[A-Z]", formula)
['X', 'B', 'D']
```

Or a solution using `str.split` that doesn't use regular expressions:

```
>>> [s[0] for s in formula.split('+')]
['X', 'B', 'D']
```

Comment: Ah! I think I understand the logic. To me, `re.findall("^([A-Z])|[+]([A-Z])", formula)` ==> `[('X', ''), ('', 'B'), ('', 'D')]` `because` the first group was that one that defined BOL and the second was athe letter after `+`. Thanks!

Comment: `[ x if x!='' else y for x,y in re.findall("^[ ]*([A-Z])|[+][ ]*([A-Z])", formula)]` is what I needed.